# Android multiple notifications with one channel

Tags: java, android, android-studio, push-notification

I'm creating an app which requires multiple notifications just like shown on the pic.[image]

Thing is I can't figure out how to do so. Using different notif. IDs doesn't seem to help. Do I need to create different channel for each notification ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2nd argument of PendingIntent.getBroadcast(); can't always be the same, something like this will do: PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, NOTIFICATION_ID, intent, 0);